# Iteration does not work and returns only one item

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping

I want to scrape a list of forum posts and their direct URL. The challenge is that the direct link doesn't make up the post name.

Here is the DOM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSitq.png

I can see only 1 item in my result. The following is what I've written. Is my iteration logic correct?

```
$postTitle = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]//span[1]/text()");
$postURL = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]//a/@href");

$output = '<ul>';

foreach ($postTitle as $title) $titlesArr[] = $title->nodeValue;
foreach ($postURL as $url) $urlsArr[] = $url->nodeValue;

$nodeValues = '';

for ($i=0; $i < count($nodeValues); $i++) { 
    $output .= '<li><a target="_blank" href="' . $urlsArr[$i] . '">' . $titlesArr[$i] . '</a></li>';
}

$output .= '</ul>';

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because **$nodeValues = ''**. Then, $i will never be less than count($nodeValues).
Try removing that line.